# sql select data with multiple arguments

Tags: sql, oracle

i stuck with this problem, please help!

Here is the problem:

I have a catalog and line detail table. Such as;

Line detail table: **TRANSACTIONS_LINE_DETAIL** catalog table: **CATALOG**

In **TRANSACTIONS_LINE_DETAIL** table: SQ_TRANSACTION_LINE_DETAIL_ID, RF_TRANSACTION_ID, CH_ITEM_CODE,.. columns are included.

In **CATALOG** table: CH_ITEM_CODE, CH_ITEM_NAME,.. columns are included. (CH_ITEM_CODE is unique)

TRANSACTIONS_LINE_DETAIL table and CATALOG table relates each other by their CH_ITEM_CODE columns.

So my problem is;

I wanna write a query that fetches me transaction ids (RF_TRANSACTION_ID) which has X,Y and Z item names together. (CH_ITEM_NAME).

Below code couldn't help me;

```
                        SELECT RF_TRANSACTION_ID
                          FROM TRANSACTIONS_LINE_DETAIL TLD,  CATALOG CAT 
                         WHERE TLD.CH_ITEM_CODE= CAT.CH_ITEM_CODE
                           AND CAT.CH_ITEM_NAME IN ('X', 'Y', 'Z')
                      GROUP BY RF_WO_ID
                        HAVING COUNT(1) = 3
```

The query should fetch me transaction ids that can have;

> X, Y, Z

or

> A, B, C, X, Y, Z

or

> X, Y, Z, P

but **NOT**

> X

or

> X, Y

or

> Z, Y, A, B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the condition to the `having` clause:

```
SELECT RF_TRANSACTION_ID
FROM TRANSACTIONS_LINE_DETAIL TLD join
     CATALOG CAT 
     on TLD.CH_ITEM_CODE = CAT.CH_ITEM_CODE
where cat.ch_item_name in ('X', 'Y', 'Z')
GROUP BY RF_TRANSACTION_ID
HAVING sum(case when CAT.CH_ITEM_NAME = 'X' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when CAT.CH_ITEM_NAME = 'Y' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when CAT.CH_ITEM_NAME = 'Z' then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

This is an example of a "set-within-sets" query.  I like doing these with the logic in the `having` clause, because it makes it more general.

This version includes a `where` clause, which (in your case) makes the query more efficient.

Each condition in the `having` clause is counting the row that match a particular condition.

To add `Q`, for instance, is quite easy (this condition is in your query but not in the sample results):

```
SELECT RF_TRANSACTION_ID
FROM TRANSACTIONS_LINE_DETAIL TLD join
     CATALOG CAT 
     on TLD.CH_ITEM_CODE = CAT.CH_ITEM_CODE
GROUP BY RF_TRANSACTION_ID
HAVING sum(case when CAT.CH_ITEM_NAME = 'X' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when CAT.CH_ITEM_NAME = 'Y' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when CAT.CH_ITEM_NAME = 'Z' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when CAT.CH_ITEM_NAME = 'Q' then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

If you wanted to find transactions with X, Y, Z, but *not* Q, the last condition would be `= 0`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it seems it costs so much.. line detail table record count is nearly 100M and the other one is about 1M.

Comment: @mikhail . . . How does this compare to your method?  If there are few items with these names, you can add `where cat.ch_item_name in ('X', 'Y', 'Z')` to limit the processing.

Comment: yes, it is much faster right now. thank you again. If you dont mind i updated the first script you wrote.